# What does my machine in these 30 seconds?

Tags: boot

What does my machine in these 30 seconds:

```
[   38.832388] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   65.091297] audit_printk_skb: 168 callbacks suppressed
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:03.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express MEI Controller (rev 02)
00:03.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express PT IDER Controller (rev 02)
00:03.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Serial KT Controller (rev 02)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 92)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801IO (ICH9DO) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801IR/IO/IH (ICH9R/DO/DH) 4 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
```

Ok, thanks for editing and for the answer.
I'll try with a better identation.

`blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="3b0b1076-a740-43b0-b73e-22414984828a" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="32d85c9a-bced-4006-a4e8-a861573cd6ff" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="System" UUID="4EDFF203322F72EA" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Volume" UUID="1679296936D93232" TYPE="ntfs"
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3b0b1076-a740-43b0-b73e-22414984828a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=32d85c9a-bced-4006-a4e8-a861573cd6ff none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: The phrasing of your question doesn't make much sense... Do you mean "What is my  machine doing in this 30 second time period?" or something else.

Comment: Possibly some mounting problem. Check this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2206398 . Also `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` outputs may be helpful if attached to your question.

Comment: What are your boot parameters? If you have `quiet`, try to remove it.

Comment: @fkraiem : `quiet` removed yet two weeks ago.

Comment: @whtyger: i can try with boot-repair...

Comment: Your `/dev/sda1` UUIDs look OK. This `/dev/sdb` drive - is it internal HDD or external USB hard drive? If the latter, did you try removing it to compare the delays of the booting process?

Comment: `/dev/sdb/` is a HDD with Windows. I can unplug it and try again.